# Rails Uninitalized Constant Error on Startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization

I have a local development machine which has started to give me the following error on starting up the Rails server:

```
    C:/Software/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/i
nflector.rb:404: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::String (N
ameError)   

    from C:/Software/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Software/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
31:in `require'
```

No Rails specific updates have been made on this machine, only automatic Windows updates.

Anyone have a clue on this? I cannot upgrade to Rails 2.3.5.

Thanks!
Vikram

gem list gives:

```
actionmailer (2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.2, 2.2.2, 2.1.0)
actionpack (2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.2, 2.2.2, 2.1.0)
activerecord (2.3.4, 2.3.2, 2.2.2, 2.1.0)
activeresource (2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.2, 2.2.2, 2.1.0)
activesupport (2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.2, 2.2.2, 2.1.0)
bullet (1.7.1)
capistrano (2.5.5, 2.5.0)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
echoe (3.1.1)
facebooker (1.0.54)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
highline (1.5.0, 1.4.0)
json (1.1.9)
json_pure (1.2.0)
memcache-client (1.7.4)
mime-types (1.16)
mislav-will_paginate (2.3.11, 2.3.8, 2.3.4)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mysql (2.7.3)
net-scp (1.0.2, 1.0.1)
net-sftp (2.0.2, 2.0.1)
net-ssh (2.0.11, 2.0.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
parseexcel (0.5.2)
rack (1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
rails (2.3.4, 2.3.2, 2.2.2)
rake (0.8.7, 0.8.4, 0.8.2)
rmagick (2.6.0)
rubyforge (2.0.3, 1.0.3)
rubyzip (0.9.1)
spreadsheet-excel (0.3.5.1)
```

Comment: Can you post the results of running `gem list`

Comment: Sure. I have edited the question to show gem list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let everyone know. The error was due to a power outage that caused the computer to shut down incorrectly, and which corrupted some of the files on the machine.

Uninstalling every Rails version and dependencies, and reinstalling them fixed the issue (although uninstalling just the version that was being used could also have done the trick).

Vikram

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upgrade to rails 2.3.5?  If so you may want to upgrade your ActiveRecord to 2.3.5 as well (as well as install the 2.3.5 rails gems).

If not, you may want to uninstall your 2.3.5 versions of actionmailer, actionpack, activerecord, activeresource, activesupport and see if that helps.

Comment: I wasn't trying to upgrade to 2.3.5. I tried to upgrade to check if that would help. 

I uninstalled of them and still get the same error. :(